# C# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq

It is just an example of my situation

```
 var query =
    Employee.Join(department,
                emp => emp.depId,
                dep=> dep.Id,
                (emp, dep) =>
                    new EmployeeModel{ Name = emp.Name, Total = GetTotal(emp)});

   

    public string GetTotal(emp)
{
    //dynamically decide which column to pass to the stored procedure, that is 
    //why I am passing the whole object
    total = sp(emp.column1, emp.column2);//here I pass the parameters to SP    
    return total;
}
```

And I get an exception here, I do not know how to solve it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is going to happen. Linq to entities doesn't know what `GetTotal()` is, and given how it is going to call a stored procedure for each row returned I suggest you move the join itself to a stored procedure and forget LINQ for a while here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable.

### IEnumerable

An object that implements IEnumerable, represents and enumerable sequence. It holds everything to ask for the first element of the sequence, and as long as you've got an element, you can ask for the next one.

At its lowest level this is done by calling GetEnumerator and repeatedly calling MoveNext / Current, until there are no more elements.

Higher level methods as `foreach` and IEnumerable LINQ methods that don't return `IEnumerable<TResult>`, like ToList / ToDictionary / Count / FirstOrDefault / Any / etc. all deep inside use GetEnumerator / MoveNext / Current.

### IQueryable

An object that implements IQueryable, doesn't represent the enumerable sequence itself, it represents **the potential to get an Enumerable sequence**.

For this, an IQueryable has an `Expression` and a `Provider`.

The Expression represents what data must be fetched in some generic format. The Provider knows who will provide the data (quite often a database management system) and what language is used to communicate with this DBMS (usually SQL).

As long as you concatenate LINQ methods that return `IQueryable<...>`, you are only changing the Expression. The DBMS is not contacted.

When you start enumerating the sequence, either directly by calling GetEnumerator / MoveNext, or indirectly by using foreach, or calling a LINQ method that returns anything but `IQueryable<...>`, then the Expression is sent to the Provider who will translate the Expression into SQL and fetch the data. The fetched data is  represented as an enumerable sequence, which your code can access using MoveNext / Current repeatedly.

The problem is, that your provider doesn't know how to translate the call to `GetTotal(...)` into SQL. In fact, although the guys who wrote Entity Framework did a marvellous job, there are several LINQ methods that your Provider can't handle. See [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

So you can't call your own methods when using IQueryable. Luckily there are several solutions for this.

### AsEnumerable

Your DBMS is extremely optimized to select the data in the query. One of the slower parts of a database query is the transfer from the selected data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of data being transferred.

If your DBMS doesn't need the output of your method, consider using `AsEnumerable()`. This will transfer your selected data to your local process in a smart way.
Depending on the Provider, it can fetch the data "per page", instead of fetching all data, so if you end your LINQ with `Take(3).ToList()`, it will not have fetched all 1000 Customers from your database.

The result of the fetched data is represented as an `IEnumerable<...>` to you. The LINQ statements after that are executed on your local machine, so you can call your local methods.

Alas, as you use `GetTotal` in your Join, you can't use this method. If you would use AsEnumerable before the Join, you would transfer all Employees and all Departments to your local process, who had to do the join.

### Convert GetEmp

You use GetEmp in parameter resultSelector of your Join. This parameter has the following generic format

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>> resultSelector
```

Of in your case:

```
Expression<Employee, Department, EmployeeModel>
```

So you'll have to change your GetEmp, such that it creates this expression.

```
Expression<Employee, Department, EmployeeModel> EmployeeModelExpression =

(employee, department) => new EmployeeModel
{
    Name = employee.Name,
    Total = ???
};
```

Alas you forgot to tell us how you calculate the Total in SP.
You should only use fairly simple calculations, like:

```
Total = employee.Column1 + employee.Column2,
Total = (employee.Column1 < 50) ? employee.Column1 : employee.Column2,
Total = employee.Column1 ?? employee.Column2
```